# Python: Select multiple columns in a dataframe from another dataframe without loop

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (df1) that has 3000 columns. Each columns corresponds to a stock ticker. I export in a DataFrame (df2) using `pd.read_csv` a csv file of 500 stock tickers (1 column and 500 rows, excluding the index). How can I extract into a new datafame from df1 the 500 columns that match the stock tickers in df2?

I can write a loop that iterates over each row in df2 and extract one column at a time from df1 but I find this slow and probably not the most efficient way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use loc directly to select some columns from your DataFrame (to use @waitingkuo's example):

```
In [11]: df1.loc[:, df2.stock]  # equivalent to df1[df2.stock]
Out[11]: 
   s1  s3
0   1   3
1   4   6
2   7   9
3  10  12
```

Comment: This one is much better!

Comment: Fantastic! Works great and efficient.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html#database-style-dataframe-joining-merging).

For simplifying your question, say we have three stock, s1, s2, and s3 in `df1`. And we only have s1 and s3 in `df2`

```
In [35]: df1
Out[35]: 
   s1  s2  s3
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
3  10  11  12

[4 rows x 3 columns]

In [36]: df2
Out[36]: 
  stock
0    s1
1    s3

[2 rows x 1 columns]
```

To join `df2` and `df1`, we need to set the column to join on, and transpose `df1` so that we have stock name as index:

```
In [37]: df2.join(df1.T, on='stock')
Out[37]: 
  stock  0  1  2   3
0    s1  1  4  7  10
1    s3  3  6  9  12

[2 rows x 5 columns]
```

If you're similar with SQL, just think it as

```
SELECT * FROM df2 JOIN df1.T ON df2.stock = df1.T.index
```